# setImageResource undefined in java

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView initialized with an image. Then in java when process accept some condition I want to change the picture. I made this code

```
if(i==1)
{
    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imgv=setImageResource(R.drawable.player1);
}
```

But I get an error in java saying `the method setImageResource() is undefined in the type javaFile`. What does that mean? How to overcome this error? Is there any better way for changing an image like the way I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.player1);
```

Instead of:

```
imgv=setImageResource(R.drawable.player1);
```

Because [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) is a method of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

you should be calling `imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.player1);`, note the period character, you have used an equals character.